# django template rendering default being evaluated when not False

Tags: django, django-templates

Consider the following snippet of django template:

```
{{ user.get_full_name|default:user.username }}
```

I would expect that if `user.get_full_name` is successful, then it would use that value, and ignore the rest. However, when I try on a user model which has a `get_full_name()` method, but no username attribute, it fails, saying the object doesn't have a username (even though it does have a `get_full_name`). Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: We would expect that the default value is always available, because it is *default*. So if some objects will not have a username, the username attribute shouldn't be the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templatetags call Python functions. Like [this one](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L811) for the `default` filter

```
@register.filter(is_safe=False)
def default(value, arg):
    """If value is unavailable, use given default."""
    return value or arg
```

So even if the first value is `True`, the second value is still required, because they are both handed to the Python function by the template engine.